# Pattern Design Program not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have two codes that work together to draw patterns using import turtle. I don't know if the code works properly or if it is 100% correct because I get multiple errors that I don't know how to fix. I have tried fixing them but they keep appearing. My program should draw patterns according to the user's input. I am getting indentation errors, and I try to fix them but it is still not working. Please help!

File 1 of code:

```
import pattern as p

def main():
    p.setup()

playAgain = True
while playAgain:
    print("Choose a mode")
    print("1) Rectangle Pattern")
    print("2) Circle Pattern")
    print("3) Super Pattern")
mode = eval(input("Which mode do you want to play? 1, 2 or 3: "))

if mode == 1:
    width = input("Enter width for the rectangles: ")
    height = input("Enter height for the rectangles: ")
    count = input("Enter how many rectangles you'd like in the pattern: ")
    centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))
p.drawRectanglePattern(centerX, centerY, p.drawRectanglePattern.offset, width, height, count, p.drawRectanglePattern.rotations)

elif mode == 2:
    width = input("Enter width for the circles: ")
    height = input("Enter height for the circles: ")
    count = input("Enter how many circles you'd like in the pattern: ")
    centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))
p.drawCirclePattern(centerX, centerY, offset, radius, count)


elif mode == 3:
    width = input("Enter width for the super pattern: ")
    height = input("Enter height for the super pattern: ")
    count = input("Enter how many super patterns you'd like in the pattern: ")
    centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))

if num == "":
p.drawSuperPattern()
else:
p.drawSuperPattern(eval(num))


print("Do you want to play again?")
print("1) Yes, and keep drawings")
print("2) Yes, and clear drawings")
print("3) No, I am all done")
response = eval(input("Choose 1, 2, or 3: "))

if response == 1:
        playAgain = True
    if response == 2:
        pattern.reset()
        playAgain = True
    else:
        playAgain = False
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        pattern.done()

main()
```

File 2 called pattern.py

```
import turtle
import random

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800

def setup():
turtle.screensize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
turtle.speed(0)

def setRandomColor():
colors = ["misty rose", "lavender", "blue", "gold", "forest green", "orange"]
random.choice(colors)


def drawRectangle(centerX, centerY, width, height):
turtle.pd()
turtle.color((setRandomColor()))
for b in range(2):
turtle.forward(height)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(width)
turtle.left(90)

def drawRectanglePattern(centerX, centerY, offset, width, height, count, rotation):
offset = 0
for c in range(count):
rotation = (360/count)
offset += 1
nextRect = (rotation/(height/2) + offset)
turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(nextRect)
drawRectangle(centerX, centerY, width, height)
```

Comment: What have you done to fix the indentation errors?

Comment: Each indentation error should give you a line number. Go to that line, fix the indent to be proper, then run it again and go to the next error.

Comment: I changed the indentations, but still get errors on some of them.

Comment: Please show us the updated source code. We can't help you if you don't. Additionally you could format your source code for SO with ` ` `. Just without the blanks in between instead of indenting it by four blanks.

Comment: @csabinho What updated source code? The code that you see is the code that I have written with all the possible fixes that I was able to do. I am new using python so I thought I could get some help around here. That is all the code that I have, and sorry if my post/question is not perfect. I am learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a disaster.  The indentation is non-existent for the most part.  You call functions that don't exist.  You pass arguments that you ignore.  You import the second file under one name but invoke it by another name.  You repeat fixed calculations inside loops. Etc.

This appears to be an example of writing too much code without testing anything, and then hoping it works.  Write small chunks, test small chunks, write more small chunks and test them, etc.

Here's a rewrite of your code to make it basically function:

The `pattern.py` library:

```
import turtle
from random import choice

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800

COLORS = ["misty rose", "lavender", "blue", "gold", "forest green", "orange"]

def setup():
    turtle.screensize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    turtle.speed('fastest')

def reset():
    turtle.clearscreen()

def getRandomColor():
    return choice(COLORS)

def drawRectangle(centerX, centerY, width, height):
    turtle.goto(centerX - width/2, centerY - height/2)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.color(getRandomColor())

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)

def drawRectanglePattern(centerX, centerY, width, height, count):
    rotation = 360 / count

    for _ in range(count):
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.left(rotation)
        drawRectangle(centerX, centerY, width, height)

def drawCirclePattern(centerX, centerY, radius, count):
    pass

def drawSuperPattern(centerX, centerY, width, height, count):
    pass
```

The main program that invokes the library:

```
import pattern

def main():

    while True:
        print("Choose a mode")
        print("1) Rectangle Pattern")
        print("2) Circle Pattern")
        print("3) Super Pattern")

        mode = int(input("Which mode do you want to play? 1, 2 or 3: "))

        pattern.setup()

        if mode == 1:
            width = int(input("Enter width for the rectangles: "))
            height = int(input("Enter height for the rectangles: "))
            count = int(input("Enter how many rectangles you'd like in the pattern: "))
            centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))

            pattern.drawRectanglePattern(int(centerX), int(centerY), width, height, count)
        elif mode == 2:
            radius = int(input("Enter the radius for the circles: "))
            count = int(input("Enter how many circles you'd like in the pattern: "))
            centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))

            pattern.drawCirclePattern(int(centerX), int(centerY), radius, count)
        elif mode == 3:
            width = int(input("Enter width for the super pattern: "))
            height = int(input("Enter height for the super pattern: "))
            count = int(input("Enter how many super patterns you'd like in the pattern: "))
            centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))

            pattern.drawSuperPattern(int(centerX), int(centerY), width, height, count)

        print("Do you want to play again?")
        print("1) Yes, and keep drawings")
        print("2) Yes, and clear drawings")
        print("3) No, I am all done")

        response = int(input("Choose 1, 2, or 3: "))

        if response == 1:
            pass
        elif response == 2:
            pattern.reset()
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break

main()
```

A major issue that you should address, besides filling in the missing functions, is rid your program of the `eval()` calls.  It's not a routine you should be using, despite any convenience it might provide.

**EXAMPLE USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Choose a mode
1) Rectangle Pattern
2) Circle Pattern
3) Super Pattern
Which mode do you want to play? 1, 2 or 3: 1
Enter width for the rectangles: 150
Enter height for the rectangles: 275
Enter how many rectangles you'd like in the pattern: 17
Enter center position (x, y): (25, 75)
Do you want to play again?
1) Yes, and keep drawings
2) Yes, and clear drawings
3) No, I am all done
Choose 1, 2, or 3: 3
Thanks for playing!
>
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

[image]